# How to write enumerate such that I get item side by side with some vertical spacing

Tags: align, enumerate, itemize

I am using enumerate but it is like vertical alignment. I want my items side by side ( 2-3 items in a single line ) with some vertical spacing.

[image]

See my code for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item $\phi_i \mid G_i = 1_{G_i}$

Let $g \in G_i$, $\phi_i ( g ) = g$
\item $\psi_1 + \psi_2 \cdots \psi_t =1_G $
\item Im $\phi_i = G_i$

\item $\phi_i\phi_i = \phi_i $
\item $\psi_i \psi_i = \psi_i$
\item Im $\psi_i = G_i (i \le r-1)$



\item  $\phi_i \phi_j = 0_G ( i \neq j )$
\item $\psi_i \psi_j = 0_G ( i \neq j)$
\item Im $\psi_1 =H_i ( i \ge r )$


\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using tablists package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tablists}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabenum}
  \tabenumitem $\phi_i \mid G_i = 1_{G_i}$ Let $g \in G_i$, $\phi_i ( g ) = g$
  \tabenumitem $\psi_1 + \psi_2 \cdots \psi_t =1_G $
  \tabenumitem Im $\phi_i = G_i$

  \tabenumitem $\phi_i\phi_i = \phi_i $
  \tabenumitem $\psi_i \psi_i = \psi_i$
  \tabenumitem Im $\psi_i = G_i (i \le r-1)$

  \tabenumitem  $\phi_i \phi_j = 0_G ( i \neq j )$
  \tabenumitem $\psi_i \psi_j = 0_G ( i \neq j)$
  \tabenumitem Im $\psi_1 =H_i ( i \ge r )$
\end{tabenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the solutions. I am using `tasks` package. You may probably want to try a combination of `enumerate`(or `enumitem`) and `multicol` packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}
%%%%%
\usepackage{tasks}
\NewTasks[counter-format=tsk[1].]{Enumerate}[\item]
%%%%%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{Enumerate}(2)
\item*(2) $\phi_i \mid G_i = 1_{G_i}$
Let $g \in G_i$, $\phi_i ( g ) = g$
\item $\psi_1 + \psi_2 \cdots \psi_t =1_G $
\item Im $\phi_i = G_i$
\item $\phi_i\phi_i = \phi_i $
\item $\psi_i \psi_i = \psi_i$
\item Im $\psi_i = G_i (i \le r-1)$
\item  $\phi_i \phi_j = 0_G ( i \neq j )$
\item $\psi_i \psi_j = 0_G ( i \neq j)$
\item Im $\psi_1 =H_i ( i \ge r )$
\end{Enumerate}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on `multicols`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\phi_i \mid G_i = 1_{G_i}$\\
Let $g \in G_i$, $\phi_i ( g ) = g$
\item $\psi_1 + \psi_2 \cdots \psi_t =1_G $
\item Im $\phi_i = G_i$
\item $\phi_i\phi_i = \phi_i $
\item $\psi_i \psi_i = \psi_i$
\item Im $\psi_i = G_i (i \le r-1)$
\item  $\phi_i \phi_j = 0_G ( i \neq j )$
\item $\psi_i \psi_j = 0_G ( i \neq j)$
\item Im $\psi_1 =H_i ( i \ge r )$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? The solution loads the `enumitem` package with the option `inline`; this sets up an environment called `enumerate*` which, you guessed it, creates inline-style enumerated lists.

[image]

Note that I redefined `\Im` to act like a math operator. (I'm assuming that "Im" means "image". Do correct me if I'm wrong.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\Im\relax % make "\Im" into a math operator
\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{enumerate*}
\item $\phi_i \mid G_i = 1_{G_i}$; 
let $g \in G_i$, $\phi_i ( g ) = g$
\item $\psi_1 + \psi_2+\cdots+\psi_t =1_G$
\item $\Im\phi_i = G_i$
\item $\phi_i\phi_i = \phi_i$
\item $\psi_i\psi_i = \psi_i$
\item $\Im\psi_i = G_i$ ($i \le r-1$)
\item $\phi_i \phi_j = 0_G$ ($i \neq j$)
\item $\psi_i \psi_j = 0_G$ ($i \neq j$)
\item $\Im\psi_1 = H_i$ ($i \ge r$)
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```